# Propagate maximum value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I think this is a relatively easy question since I know there is a simple answer in numpy, but I can't find it anymore.

I have a numpy array, say `[1, 2, 10, 5, 6, 12, 9, 9, 8]`

I want to go through it from beginning to end and to keep only the maximum value seen so far, for example the answer would be `[1, 2, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12]`

It is very easy to solve with a single loop but some times ago I learned about a numpy function that does the job quickly and that is also compact. I am looking for this method.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ufunc.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html), to accumulate the result of applying a function, `maximum` in this case, over all elements:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 10, 5, 6, 12, 9, 9, 8])

np.maximum.accumulate(a)
# array([ 1,  2, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12], dtype=int32)
```